# Start/stop tomcat on remote server from gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: java, spring-boot, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to write a script to deploy my Spring Boot application from gitlab using the **gitlab-ci.yml** file. Following are the contents of the file.

```
image: maven:3-jdk-8

services:
    - docker:dind

stages:
    - build
    - deploy

build:
    stage: build
    script: 
        - echo "Packaging"
        - mvn clean package -DskipTests
    artifacts:
        expire_in: 1 week
        when: always
        paths:
            - target/app.war

deploy:
    stage: deploy
    dependencies:
        - build
    script:
        - "#!/bin/sh"
        - chmod og= $PRODUCTION_SERVER_PASSWORD
        - scp -i "$PRODUCTION_SERVER_PASSWORD" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no target/app.war $PRODUCTION_SERVER_USER@$PRODUCTION_SERVER:/home/ubuntu/wars
        - ssh -i "$PRODUCTION_SERVER_PASSWORD" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $PRODUCTION_SERVER_USER@$PRODUCTION_SERVER sh /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh stop
        - ssh -i "$PRODUCTION_SERVER_PASSWORD" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $PRODUCTION_SERVER_USER@$PRODUCTION_SERVER rm -r /opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT*
        - ssh -i "$PRODUCTION_SERVER_PASSWORD" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $PRODUCTION_SERVER_USER@$PRODUCTION_SERVER cp -r /home/ubuntu/wars/app.war /opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
        - ssh -i "$PRODUCTION_SERVER_PASSWORD" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $PRODUCTION_SERVER_USER@$PRODUCTION_SERVER sh /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh start
    environment:
        name: production
        url: <server-url>
    when: manual
```

When the deploy stage is triggered, it gives me error in the line

```
- ssh -i "$PRODUCTION_SERVER_PASSWORD" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $PRODUCTION_SERVER_USER@$PRODUCTION_SERVER sh /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh stop
```

The error that occurs is

```
Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined
At least one of these environment variable is needed to run this program
```

However when I add

```
- echo $JAVA_HOME
```

under `script` in `deploy` stage, it prints out `/usr/local/openjdk-8`. I have not been able to understand this; why does it say `JAVA_HOME` is not defined. Do I have to define `JAVA_HOME` explicitly, and if so where and how do I do it?

Comment: Are you running `echo $JAVA_HOME` in the production server on in CI server?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam I'm writing `ssh -i "$PRODUCTION_SERVER_PASSWORD" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $PRODUCTION_SERVER_USER@$PRODUCTION_SERVER echo $JAVA_HOME` under `script` of `deploy` stage. That means it's on the production server right?

Comment: Ye it is in the production server

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
script:
        - "#!/bin/sh"
        - chmod og= $PRODUCTION_SERVER_PASSWORD
        - scp -i "$PRODUCTION_SERVER_PASSWORD" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no target/app.war $PRODUCTION_SERVER_USER@$PRODUCTION_SERVER:/home/ubuntu/wars
        - ssh -i "$PRODUCTION_SERVER_PASSWORD" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $PRODUCTION_SERVER_USER@$PRODUCTION_SERVER "
          sh /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh stop
          rm -r /opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT*
          cp -r /home/ubuntu/wars/app.war /opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
          export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/openjdk-8
          /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh start
          "
    environment:
        name: production
```

You don't need to perform multiple ssh, second if the JAVA_HOME is correct, then you can just do a simple `export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk/bin/` and you are set.

Comment: I still get the same error that JAVA_HOME is not defined, although when I echo JAVA_HOME, it shows the path is defined.

Comment: @KshitijBajracharya - I've edited my answer, what was happening before and in your case is you're trying to start catalina.sh with a new shell ```sh``` where this variable is actually not available and so the error is right, instead of running in a new shell, just try to start catalina.sh in the same shell where we set JAVA_HOME.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still didn't work. I managed to fix it by adding the PATH to JAVA_HOME for the super user so that I wouldn't have to export JAVA_HOME in the script.